# How to resolve the parent POM of a dependency that uses the dynamic version

Tags: maven

I am building a multiple modules project. The project structure likes:

```
 -Build
       -Local
         -POM.xml (Master)

-Main Project
   -Module A 

-Libs Project
   -Libs Project A
```

The Libs Project A has the POM has the dynamic version from it's parent's POM

```xml
   <parent>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>libs</artifactId>
    <version>${release.version}</version>
   </parent>
    <!-- this POM -->
    <groupId>com.myproject.libs</groupId>
    <artifactId>http</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
```

When I run maven build and pass the version parameter to build "module A", the maven can not find the POM of the libs project.

> Reason: Cannot find parent: com.myproject:libs for project:
>   com.myproject.libs:http:bundle:1.0.0 for project
>   com.myproject.libs:http:bundle:1.0.0

Answer (score 2):

*STOP NOW*

There are a number of XPath locations within the POM where property substitution is never going to work in any way that is useable.

- `/project/parent/groupId`
- `/project/parent/artifactId`
- `/project/parent/version`
- `/project/groupId`
- `/project/artifactId`
- `/project/version`
- `/project/packaging`

The reason for this is that the reactor build must be deterministic.

When you try to use properties in these locations it will *appear to work*, in other words Maven will not shoot your foot off immediately.... but when you try to do anything further on Maven will kindly shoot your foot off.

Perhaps we should change Maven to shoot your foot off initially... perhaps that would stop people thinking that putting property expansion in those elements is supported.